# Knife tool, Subdivide faces, edge select do not work in blender at all to make a rudimentary split face

Tags: modeling, faces, edges, knife-tool

I dont understand why something that should be so simple in any 3d modeling software doesn't work in Blender

All I want to do is splice these faces to add a door to my floor plan

I tried using the knife tool, I selected on the first edge, then dragged to the opposing edge. Clicked Enter, nothing happened, no split, no new faces or new vertices

I tried selecting opposing edges, for some reason when I select the opposing edge with SHIFT, it just select the adjacent edge to the currently elected edge instead, and Subdivide operation creates a split between the wrong edges.

I used to be able to select opposing edge by holding ctrl and dragging, but now that I have 3 edges instead of 2, It doesn't work. As you can see, it worked on the first two edges, but now I am stuck because I cannot subdivide the face below, and I cannot Ctrl+Z out of it

All I want to do is split the face down the middle, how do I do this?

Why doesn't the knife tool do what it's supposed to?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use CTRL+R. This will divide the planes along the circumference.
[image]
And also after pressing the left mouse button will allow you to choose where exactly you want to divide the faces.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

That one lonely edge causes n-gons, making it all harder.
Keep your life simple and use loopcuts and quads ;)

1. Use three loopcuts to define the doorframe
2. Select the three faces and press *Delete > Faces* to remove
3. Select bottom edge and press <kbd>F</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd>  <kbd>F</kbd>  to complete the doorframe

[image]